# Compiling C++ GUI for Windows (on macOS)

Tags: c++, windows, macos, user-interface, gtkmm

I'm using macOS Catalina (v10.15.7) to compile the following example code from gtkmm's [online book](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en):

```cpp
#include <gtkmm.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create(argc, argv, "org.gtkmm.examples.base");
    Gtk::Window window;
    window.set_default_size(200, 200);
    return app->run(window);
}
```

It compiles fine for macOS, but if I try to compile it for Windows using:

```
x86_64-w64-mingw32-g++ -o app.exe main.cpp -std=c++11 `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

Besides various warnings, I get the following errors for which I couldn't find almost any solutions on Google and Stack Overflow:

```
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.2_1/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:75:1: error: 'uid_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'pid_t'?
   75 | uid_t            g_credentials_get_unix_user      (GCredentials    *credentials,
      | ^~~~~
      | pid_t
/usr/local/Cellar/glib/2.66.2_1/include/glib-2.0/gio/gcredentials.h:79:52: error: 'uid_t' has not been declared
   79 |                                                    uid_t           uid,
      |                                                    ^~~~~
/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.64.5/include/giomm-2.4/giomm/credentials.h:243:3: error: 'uid_t' does not name a type; did you mean 'pid_t'?
  243 |   uid_t get_unix_user();
      |   ^~~~~
      |   pid_t
/usr/local/Cellar/glibmm/2.64.5/include/giomm-2.4/giomm/credentials.h:264:22: error: 'uid_t' has not been declared
  264 |   bool set_unix_user(uid_t uid);
      |                      ^~~~~
```

Any help is much appretiated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From an [element chat room](https://riot.im/app/#/room/#cpplang:matrix.org), I was told that the `pkg-config` on macOS seems to be using the macOS version of its libraries for compiling. Even if compile-time errors like `uid_t` are resolved, the libraries wouldn't be able to link properly.

In the end, it was much easier to compile the executable directly on a Windows machine.

1. Download & install [MSYS2](https://www.msys2.org/).
2. After installation, update MSYS2:
   `pacman -Syu`
3. Install `gcc` & `mingw` packages:

   - For i686 machines:
         `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gcc`
   - For x86_64 machine:
         `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gcc`
4. Install `gtkmm` libraries:

   - For i686 machines:
         `pacman -S mingw-w64-i686-gtkmm3`
   - For x86_64 machines:
         `pacman -S mingw-w64-x86_64-gtkmm3`
5. Install `pkg-config`:
   `pacman -S pkg-config`
6. Now open `mingw64.exe` in `C:/msys64` and navigate to the directory where the source code exists.

The final cavier, compile your source code using:

```
g++ -std=c++11 hello.cpp -o myApp $(pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs | sed 's/ -I/ -isystem /g')
```

Comment: Why mingw for OS X instead of clang++ ? gtkmm is working well with clang++ when installed with homebrew. For me homebrew is the easier way to achieve it. This is what I used for my personal project.